# Spring REST and patching a list is not updating first element

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I have a problem to replace elements in a List of an object by Springs default patch-Method. I use spring-boot 2.6.7.

I have 2 related entities, a rental object which can belongs to multiple portals:

Rental:

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "rental")
public class Rental implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6281190735417544253L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "rental_portal", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "rentalId"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "portalId")
    )
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    private List<Portal> portals;
```

Portal:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "portal")
public class Portal implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8534905447925259846L;

    @Id
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(updatable = false)
    private String name;
}
```

The rental is accessible via the repository interface:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "rental")
public interface RentalRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Rental, Long> {

}
```

For my use case I want to list all portals in my rental object without calling the portal repository.

GET /rental/1

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "Test rental",
  "portals" : [ {
    "id" : 2,
    "name" : "PORTAL_2"
  } ],
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/rental/1"
    },
    "rental" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/rental/1"
    }
  }
}
```

If I call the patch method and

- add one or more portals to the rental object works fine
- send an empty list to delete all portals from the rental object works also as expected
- **if I want to replace an existing portal with another one, this has no effect. I receive the html status code 204 but the rentals portal value has not been changed**

PATCH /rental/1

```
{
  "portals": [
    {
      "id": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I think, problem here, that it cannot understand what it should do with your `portals`. I would recommend you if you want replace a single `portal`, make another endpoint for it (ex. PATCH /rental/{rentalId}/portal/{portalId}) and inside logic handling of this endpoint, you should get the `rental` get `portals` of itself, search for `portalId` you want replace, delete it, and insert new portal from request body.

Answer (score 0):

I found a suitable solution for my use case:

Instead of using a list I created a map with the portal id as the maps key. The consumer of this api just want to know to which portals this rental belongs, so I return not a map with the whole object but the keys. For this behaviour I added a custom setter and getter.

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Rental implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3647935687142095639L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "rental_portal", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "rentalId"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "portalId")
    )
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    @MapKey(name = "id")
    private Map<Long, Portal> portals;

    @JsonGetter
    public Set<Long> getPortals() {
        final Set<Long> portalKeys = new HashSet<>(this.portals.keySet());
        return portalKeys;
    }

    @JsonSetter
    public void setPortals(final Set<Long> portals) {
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(portals)) {
            this.portals.clear();
            for (final Long portalKey : portals) {
                final Portal portal = new Portal();
                portal.setId(portalKey);
                this.portals.put(portalKey, portal);
            }
        } else if (this.portals != null) {
            this.portals.clear();
        }
    }
```

Now the consumer can patch any values. For example:

PATCH /rental/1

```
{
  "portals" : [ 1]
}
```

```
{
  "portals" : [ 2]
}
```

```
{
  "portals" : [ 1, 2]
}
```

```
{
  "portals" : []
}
```